# Codeigniter Base url not working in header

Tags: css, codeigniter, url, stylesheet

I am using the codeigniter Framework and unable to link the stylesheet to the pages! I have created a header and fotter file so the stylesheet is loaded in every page. The content is passing through however no style is being passed. My file layout follows:

app
assets
index.php
system
ect..

within my assets folder i have:

assets/
css
images
js
includes

And in my header i have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="">
<title>Site Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?> assets/css/style.css"  type="text/css" media="screen" />

    </head>
    <body>
```

In my homepage i load the header and footer using: $this->load->view('header');, $this->load->view('footer');

I have checked my base url and set up a htaccess file and autoload the url helper. I have tried accessing my css file without base url (standard procedure) and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake- left a space next to   and assets/css/style.css".

Comment: to avoid this you can use base url like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>"  type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: I am going to take your advice and use it this way, to me its more tidy and will avoid this mistake again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You edit like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/css/style.css"  type="text/css" media="screen" />               "you are missing '/'"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is that you have to load the url helper in your controller where you call the homepage view (header, homepage content and footer). If someone has better, please post it.

```
$this->load->helper("url");
```